# 0.00001 Increment

Tags: c

I’m a beginner to C and I’m trying to do the 0.00001 increment in a While Loop. For example, double t = 0.00001 and I want the the loop to run every time by increment of 0.00001 ,which the second time would be 0.00002 and so on.
Can anyone please help?

This is a part of my code that I’m debugging. I’m trying to run simulation until v becomes a negative value. And every time the While Loop is true and repeat I want to it to add an increment of 0.00001

```
    t = 0.00001; 
    f = fMid;  
    v = v0; 
    x = 0;  

    // 10.2 Calculate the simulated stopping distance
    while( v >= 0)
    { 
     a = - f - (C_d)*(v*v); 

     // Calculate the new position 
     x_new = x + (v*t);  

     // Calculate the new velocity
     v_new = v + (a*t);

     x = x_new;
     v = v_new;

     ++t;
    }
```

Comment: Make an attempt.  Then if you get stuck, come back with a **specific** question.

Comment: What is the problem? One thing that you should be aware though is that your numbers would be not precisely these because `double` can't represent them exactly. See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: It is hard to assist if we don't know what your problem is.  If it that `t += 0.00001 ;` (or `t = t + 0.00001 ;`) has not ocurred to you, or have you discovered that incrementing a binary floating-point value by a decimal causes a "drift" away from the expected value?

Comment: To what @Clifford said - to avoid the accumulating drift, you can have an *integer* counter `i` and have `t=i*0.00001`. Also will have preventing the case when `t` and `t+0.00001` are actually resulting in the same representation (that's it will no longer be incrementing).

Comment: I’ve edit the question and posted my code up there.Kindly have a look thanks!

Comment: How do you think `++t` is supposed to increment t by `0.00001`?

Comment: I was trying to update the x and v with a new x and v with an increment of 0.00001 second until the updated v is a negative value

Comment: Yeah I have no idea how to do the 0.00001 increment so please ignore that

Comment: Do you all think it might be fair to let the OP respond to comments (as he has done) before voting to close?

Comment: @Maxx  You would do well to include the data types in your code fragment.  The difference in behaviour given the use of `double` or `float` can be significant.

Comment: There is no question in your post except “Can anyone please help?” Edit your post to ask a specific question. Is the code you have not working? What does it do wrong? Explain what it is doing (preferably add `printf` statements to show values as it goes) and explain what you want it to do instead. Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: As others have pointed out, you can't repeatedly add `0.00001` to a `double` without running into rounding errors. But why do you need to ? Perhaps `int us=0;// elapsed time in microseconds ... us+=10;` would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since the floating point arithmetic is not precise (see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) ) a "naive" approach such as:

```
double t = 0.0;
while (t < N) {   // Or your specific condition here
    t += 0.00001;
}
```

might not be working having the possible issues:

1. At each iteration the error caused by the imprecise calculation will accumulate and will become larger the longer the loop is.
2. At some point the numbers `t` and `t+0.00001` might become *equal* because the `double` representation might not be able to distinguish between them.

To prevent (2) and to minimize the effect of (1) one can use an integer counter instead and recalculate the value of `t` based on it at each loop:

```
unsigned int ii = 0;
double t;
while (ii < N) {   // Or your specific condition here
    t = ii * 0.00001;
    ii ++;
}
```

Comment: But this will be replacing my v in the whole loop

Comment: @Maxx This is a general approach. You adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Or perhaps do you mean to make another while loop inside my while loop code?

Answer (score 1):

If you take the intuitive approach and simply increment `t` thus:

```
double t = 0 ;

while( t < target )
{
    t += 0.00001 ;
}
```

You will find that the accumulated error caused by incrementing a *binary* floating point by a *decimal* real value (necessarily imprecisely converted to *binary*) soon causes the `t` to no longer be an accurate multiple of 0.00001.  To prevent that you would do better to use:

```
double t = 0 ;
int i = 0 ;

while( t < target )
{
    t = i * 0.00001 ;
    i++ ;
}
```

For example consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double target = 20000.0 ;
    int i = 0 ;
    double t = 0 ;
    while( t < target )
    {
        t += 0.00001 ;
        i++ ;
    }
    printf( "%d : %f\n", i, t ) ;

    t = 0 ;
    i = 0 ;
    while( t < target )
    {
        t = i * 0.00001 ;
        i++ ;
    }
    printf( "%d : %f\n", i, t ) ;
}
```

In my test the output was:

```
2000000037 : 20000.000005
2000000001 : 20000.000000
```

The first loop did 36 more iterations due to the accumulated floating point error.  That may be negligible or even irrelevant in some cases, but it is a common source of confusion, error and non-deterministic behaviour that you may need to be cautious of.

That is not the most serious issue however.  If the target value is very
large and the increment very small, the first loop may never terminate because the increment must first be normalised to the same precision as the value of `t` and the nature of floating point representation is such that the increment may become zero.  `double` is good for approximately 15 significant figures do if say:

```
              __15 digits__
             /              \
target    == 1000000000.00000
increment ==          0.00000100000000000000
                             \__15 digits__/
// After normalisation:
increment == 0000000000.00000
             \__15 digits__/
```

`increment` is smaller than the *precision* of `target`, so when `increment` is transformed to the same *precision*, being smaller than that precision, it becomes zero, and no increment occurs.  The problem becomes more acute if you use `float` which is good for only 6 significant decimal digits.

Specifically with respec to your code:

```
    #define INCREMENT 0.00001
    ...

    double t = INCREMENT; 
    ...

 // 10.2 Calculate the simulated stopping distance
    int i = 0 ;
    while( v >= 0)
    { 
     a = - f - (C_d)*(v*v); 

     // Calculate the new position 
     x_new = x + (v*t);  

     // Calculate the new velocity
     v_new = v + (a*t);

     x = x_new;
     v = v_new;

     // Increment t
     i++ ;
     t = i * INCREMENT ;

     // ++t;           // Not this
     // t += INCREMENT // or this

    }
```

Comment: I see! I think I get the idea now thank man!

Comment: Usually, though, when solving an ODE, *v* (and *x*) are updated using the *increment* *dt*, not the total time.

Comment: @Bob__ Indeed, but the OP had not posted code or indicated the application when I originally write the answer.  As I said, it may or may not matter depending on the application, bad a novice understanding the gotcha and getting int good habits is important.